# Django Migrations - How can I migrate my own django models without any inbuild models like auth,sessions,sites,admin etc

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I have a requirements so that its not possible to change given schema. I dont need any django inbuild models such as admin,auth,sessions,messages etc..
how can I migrate my models without the inbuild models.

I will be gratefull if you can help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can migrate your own models by doing this:

```
python manage.py makemigrations appname
python manage.py sqlmigrate appname 0001 #It is autogenerated value after makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

This is the way you can do.